# Convert SQL Query to Criteria Query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

I'm relatively new to Spring JPA CriteriaQuery. Im trying to convert my old native query in my program to criteria query and haven't been successful on join query for multiple table with conditions. I need help converting native SQL query into Criteria Query for these query below :

```
select * from student s inner join (
   select distinct on (student_id) * from class where status = 'Active' order by 
   student_id,date_register desc) c on s.id = c.user_id 
inner join teacher t on t.subject_id = c.subject_id 
where t.status = 'Active' and s.status='Active' order by s.name desc
```

---

Update :

Below code is as far as I can go cause I dont really know much. Am i in the right direction? I'm opting for Expression because i dont know how to use Join.

```
CriteriaQuery<Student> query = cb.createQuery(Student.class);
Root<Student> sRoot= query.from(Student.class);
query.select(sRoot);
        
Subquery<Integer> subquery = query.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Class> cRoot= subquery.from(CLass.class);
Expression<Integer> max = cb.max(cRoot.get("dateRegister"));
subquery.select(max);
subquery.groupBy(cRoot.get("student"));
        
query.where(
    cb.and(
        cb.in(cRoot.get("dateRegister")).value(subquery)
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show what you've tried so far

Comment: Hi @NikolaiShevchenko, thanks for the comment. I've update my post with the current code im stuck on, haven't been able to go any further cause i dont know much on this.